# egrep find a line that has at least two times the same word

Tags: regex, shell, grep

How can I use regular expression to find a line that has at least two times the same word?

I tried:

```
egrep '\w{2,}\1' file
```

But the terminal gives me the error:

> egrep: invalid backreference number

Comment: Check my edit; that should do it.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your current regex.

1. Use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for capturing words and [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to it.
2. Add `\b` [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) for limiting words to left and right side.
3. Add `.*` for matching [any amount](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of [any characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) in between.

```
echo "ABC foo ABC bar" | egrep '\b(\w{2,})\b.*\b\1\b'
```

> ABC foo ABC bar

```
echo "ABC foo ABCD bar" | egrep '\b(\w{2,})\b.*\b\1\b'
```

> `false`

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kB9cW8/1). If desired use `egrep -o` *--only-matching* to extract relevant part.
You can further use `.*?` [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) dot with [`grep`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/grep.html)`-P` *--perl-regexp*  for as few times as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
egrep '(\w{2,}).*\1' file
```

If you don't have a capturing group (`(...)`), then there's nothing to backreference.

Here's an example:

```
$ cat file
this line has the same word twice word
this line does not
this is this and that is that

$ egrep '(\w{2,}).*\1' file
this line has the same word twice word
this is this and that is that
```

Comment: Thank you, but i think the answer above solves the problem better since it added \b word boundaries on both sides.

Comment: I agree :) No problem.